# Burning subtitles into video using ffmpeg overlay on react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, ffmpeg

I have managed to complete this task on node server but it's too slow I don't want to upgrade my instance so I decided to do the conversion on the front end, my app is on react native can please somebody help me convert the code and keep the same args and options

Server code

```
// Execute the ffmpeg command to burn the subtitles into the video
const ffmpeg = spawn("ffmpeg", [
  "-i",
  "pipe:0",
  "-vf",
  `subtitles=${subtitlePath}:force_style='Alignment=10,OutlineColour=&H100000000,BorderStyle=3,Outline=1,Shadow=0,Fontsize=10'`,
  "-c:a",
  "copy",
  "-progress", "pipe:1",
  outputPath,
]);

// Pipe the videoResponse array buffer to FFmpeg
ffmpeg.stdin.write(videoResponse.data);
ffmpeg.stdin.end();

// Send the output file as a response once the process is complete
ffmpeg.on("close", () => {
  fs.readFile(outputPath, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      console.log(outputPath)
    }
  });
});
```

My try on react native but failed for several issues including, main ones are:

> No such filter: 'subtitles' Failed to inject frame into filter

> Invalid argument

> Error initializing complex filters.

This is what I come up with so far

```
  componentDidMount() {
    FFmpegKit.executeAsync(`-i ${inputFilePath} -i ${subtitleFilePath} -filter_complex "[0:v][1:s]overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10" -c:a copy ${outputFilePath}`)
    .then((session) => {
      FFmpegKit.cancel();
  
      const returnCode = session.getReturnCode();
  
      if (ReturnCode.isSuccess(returnCode)) {
        console.log('Video with subtitles was created successfully!');
      } else {
        console.log('Error creating video with subtitles');
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error creating video with subtitles', error);
    });
  }
```

If you want to see the logs you can find them below

```
 LOG  init firebase : videocap-71b4a
 LOG  Running "videocap" with {"rootTag":11,"initialProps":{}}
 LOG  Loading ffmpeg-kit-react-native.
 LOG  Loaded ffmpeg-kit-react-native-ios-https-x86_64-5.1.0.
 LOG  Error creating video with subtitles [TypeError: undefined is not a function]
 LOG  ffmpeg version n5.1.2
 LOG   Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
 LOG  
 LOG    built with Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102)
 LOG    configuration: --cross-prefix=x86_64-ios-darwin- --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode-v13.4.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.0.sdk --prefix=/Users/taner/Projects/ffmpeg-kit/prebuilt/apple-ios-x86_64/ffmpeg --pkg-config=/opt/homebrew/bin/pkg-config --enable-version3 --arch=x86_64 --cpu=x86_64 --target-os=darwin --disable-neon --disable-asm --ar=/Applications/Xcode-v13.4.1.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ar --cc=clang --cxx=clang++ --as='clang -arch x86_64 -target x86_64-apple-ios12.1-simulator -march=x86-64 -msse4.2 -mpopcnt -m64 -DFFMPEG_KIT_X86_64 -Wno-unused-function -Wno-deprecated-declarations -fstrict-aliasing -DIOS -DFFMPEG_KIT_BUILD_DATE=20220929 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode-v13.4.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.0.sdk -O2 -mios-simulator-version-min=12.1 -I/Applications/Xcode-v13.4.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/usr/include' --ranlib=/Applications/Xcode-v13.4.1.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib --strip=/Applications/Xcode-v13.4.1.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/strip --nm=/Applications/Xcode-v13.4.1.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/nm --extra-ldflags='-mios-simulator-version-min=12.1' --disable-autodetect --enable-cross-compile --enable-pic --enable-inline-asm --enable-optimizations --enable-swscale --enable-shared --disable-static --install-name-dir='@rpath' --enable-pthreads --disable-v4l2-m2m --disable-outdev=v4l2 --disable-outdev=fbdev --disable-indev=v4l2 --disable-indev=fbdev --enable-small --disable-xmm-clobber-test --disable-debug --disable-neon-clobber-test --disable-programs --disable-postproc --disable-doc --disable-htmlpages --disable-manpages --disable-podpages --disable-txtpages --disable-sndio --disable-schannel --disable-securetransport --disable-xlib --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --disable-alsa --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --disable-sdl2 --disable-openssl --enable-zlib --enable-audiotoolbox --disable-outdev=audiotoolbox --enable-bzlib --enable-videotoolbox --enable-avfoundation --enable-iconv --disable-coreimage --disable-appkit --disable-opencl --disable-opengl
 LOG    libavutil      57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
 LOG    libavcodec     59. 37.100 / 59. 37.100
 LOG    libavformat    59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100
 LOG    libavdevice    59.  7.100 / 59.  7.100
 LOG    libavfilter     8. 44.100 /  8. 44.100
 LOG    libswscale      6.  7.100 /  6.  7.100
 LOG    libswresample   4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100
 LOG  Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/Users/master/Documents/Code/videocap-mobile/media.mp4':
 LOG    Metadata:
 LOG      major_brand     :
 LOG  isom
 LOG  
 LOG      minor_version   :
 LOG  512
 LOG  
 LOG      compatible_brands:
 LOG  isomiso2avc1mp41
 LOG  
 LOG      encoder         :
 LOG  Lavf58.76.100
 LOG  
 LOG    Duration:
 LOG  00:00:11.82
 LOG  , start:
 LOG  0.000000
 LOG  , bitrate:
 LOG  813 kb/s
 LOG  
 LOG    Stream #0:0
 LOG  [0x1]
 LOG  (und)
 LOG  : Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg/bt470bg/smpte170m, progressive), 480x608, 682 kb/s
 LOG  , SAR 32757:32326 DAR 491355:614194
 LOG  ,
 LOG  24.15 fps,
 LOG  24 tbr,
 LOG  1000k tbn
 LOG   (default)
 LOG  
 LOG      Metadata:
 LOG        handler_name    :
 LOG  VideoHandler
 LOG  
 LOG        vendor_id       :
 LOG  [0][0][0][0]
 LOG  
 LOG    Stream #0:1
 LOG  [0x2]
 LOG  (und)
 LOG  : Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 126 kb/s
 LOG   (default)
 LOG  
 LOG      Metadata:
 LOG        handler_name    :
 LOG  SoundHandler
 LOG  
 LOG        vendor_id       :
 LOG  [0][0][0][0]
 LOG  
 LOG  /Users/master/Documents/Code/videocap-mobile/transcription.srt: Immediate exit requested
 LOG  Exiting normally, received signal 2.
```

Please help